# How to break early from a cartesian product recursive function once a solution is found?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, python-itertools, cartesian-product

I am analyzing the phonetic composition of words, and as part of this I have been using cartesian products to match spelling permutations with a given word. Each sound in a word can be represented by several spellings, and the program determines the correct spelling for each sound in a word. There are an unknown number of lists, of unknown length.

I am currently user itertools' product() inside of a list comprehension, i.e. brute-forced, every permutation checked before returning a value. Here is the relevant part in Python 3:

```
from itertools import product


def cartesian_match(string, iterables):
    """Gets the phonetic spelling breakdown of a word via cartesian product.

    Args:
        string (str):     String for which a matched spelling is wanted.
        iterables (list): A list of lists of unknown number and length.
                          Each sublist contains only str elements.
                          Each sublist contains all possible spellings of a
                          phoneme.

    Returns:
        list: the first matched list of spelling units.

    Example (simplified):
      Args:
        string = "python"
        iterables = [
          'p', 'pp'],['i', 'ie', 'y', 'igh'],['th'],['or', 'ou', 'e', 'o'],[
          'nd', 'nn', 'n', 'ne']

      Returns:
        ['p', 'y', 'th', 'o', 'n']

    """
    return [x for x in product(*iterables) if "".join(x) == string][0]
```

For complex words, the cartesian product is large, tens of millions of permutations. Some words take upwards of 15 minutes to compute. I have thousands of words to analyze so speed is currently an issue.

To speed things up, I need a function which returns the value as soon as it is discovered, rather than forming a cartesian product and having to run through each and every permutation. It would also allow me to optimize the sequence of elements inside each sub-list in order to get the matched value sooner.

My challenge is that I cannot figure out how to do this iteratively with an unknown number of lists of unknown length, and I've failed at any attempt to break out of a recursive function early.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: To help us answer you, can you give an example of problematic input and wanted output? Personally I am unsure where exactly you want to break the loop.

Comment: I've tried as best I can to illustrate this inside the docstring example. For that example, there are 2*4*1*4*4 = 128 permutations in the cartesian product. This is only illustrative, each word in reality has hundreds of thousands, or millions, of permutations. I'd like the function to stop and return the value ['p', 'y', 'th', 'o', 'n'] as soon as it is matched, rather than analyzing every permutation and then returning the value. Does that clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for x in in product(*iterables):
    if "".join(x) == string:
        return x
```

BTW: your function is not recursive - the title of this question is misleading.

Comment: It's the formation of the cartesian product itself, i.e. product(*iterables), that I believe takes the bulk of the computation time, not the matching part. I've been trying to move away from reliance on product() therefore for this. You're right though, this does help with the matching part. Note: the recursion in title was referring to the internals of the product() method, I'll try and clarify my post.

Comment: Nope. `product` is a generator, it does not create a whole list of results but instead returns them one by one as they're needed. Just measure it using `timeit`.

Comment: Yep, you're right. Much faster. Can't believe I didn't think to try this sooner. Thanks for putting me right!